# Post and open in new window in Asp.Net MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, window.open

How can I post a form to an HttPost Action method and open the returned View in a new window?

I've tried to find some way to do it using the window.open function and jQuery, but I can't find anything that works... It seems there should be an easy way to do this in MVC? Everything works fine returning a normal view from the post method, so all I need is to open that returned view in a new window instead (the posting page can simply stay as it is).

Any ideas?

Comment: if you do the post via jquery/ajax, you can in the callback function that handles the response from the server, take the result and forward it to a new window that you open via javascript.

Comment: How? I tried window.open in the callback of a jQuery function, but window.open expects a url, and the action method returned html... Could you please write an answer with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="yourcontroller" target="_blank">
 ...
</form>
```

Although specifying target="_blank" to open a new window is annoying to many users and makes your site less accessible, so use this only when you have a really good reason.

Comment: Right, I know it's deprecated and all, but this is only for use in a controlled login area for a very restricted number of users, so I can basically ask them if they want a new window or not :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%:Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

stevehorn wrote a [sample using jquery](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2009/06/rendering-modal-dialog-with-aspnet-mvc.html)